# Breaking up the SDL code

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am doing first examples from the "SDL Game Development Black and White" book.

The point where I have problems is in example where I should break "HelloSDL" code in one header( .h) and two cpp( .cpp) files.

Here they are:

main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

Game* g_game = 0;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    g_game = new Game();

    g_game->init("Chapter 1", 100, 100, 640, 480, 0);

    while(g_game->running())
    {
        g_game->handleEvents();
        g_game->update();
        g_game->render();
    }
    g_game->clean();


    void Game::handleEvents()
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
           switch (event.type)
           {
               case SDL_QUIT:
                   m_bRunning = false;
               break;

              default;
              break;
           }
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H_INCLUDED
#define GAME_H_INCLUDED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Game
{
public:

    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init();

    void render();
    void update();
    void handleEvents();
    void clean();

    bool running() { return m_bRunning; }

private:

    SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;

    bool m_bRunning;
};

#endif // GAME_H_INCLUDED
```

Game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

bool Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags)
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL init success\n";
        m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);

        if(m_pWindow != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "window creation success\n";
            m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, 0);

            if(m_pRenderer != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "renderer creation success\n";
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_pRenderer, 255 255, 255, 255);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "renderer init fail\n";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "window init fail\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "SDL init fail\n";
            return false;
        }

        std::cout << "init success\n";
        m_bRunning = true;

        return true;
}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(m_pRenderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer);
}

SDL_Quit()
    +{
        std::cout << "cleaning game\n";
        SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
        SDL_Quit();
    }

void Game::clean()
{
    std::cout << "cleaning game\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

After compiling it in CodeBlocks(16.11) I get next error messages:

```
Game.cpp|6|error: prototype for 'bool Game::init(const char*, int, int, int, int, int)' does not match any in class 'Game'

Game.h|12|error: candidate is: void Game::init()
```

Firstly, I got much more errors but I managed to solve it. 
There is still two more errors to solve. 
I suppose that is something wromg in Game.h file, but I cannot find it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may be coming from C background. In C++ omitting function signature at function declaration is not permitted. Basically by declaring `void init();` you declare `void Game::init(void)` function, not `bool Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags)`. So one must carefully check that function declaration does exactly match function definition. Another thing is that in C++ one should perform object initialization at constructor and cleanup at destructor.

Comment: After I changed void init() with bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags), I get this error: Build: Debug in sdl: (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @user284901 That is certainly not a complete build log.

Comment: Do you mean I missed to include some of sdl libraries in code blocks project build options?

Comment: @user284901 I mean build log should contain some actual error messages, not just useless "ld returned 1 exit status".

Comment: @user284901 The first thing would be getting complete build log.

Answer (score 0):

The init() declared in the game.h returns void, but the definition you provide returns bool.